# Best Lipschitz constant of a gradient of $f(x) = x^T A x$, where $A$ is symmetric positive definite

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, quadratic-forms, lipschitz-functions, matrix-norms

**Question**:

> What is a best Lipschitz constant of a gradient of $f(x) = x^T A x$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric positive definite and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

---

My attempt:

The gradient of $f(x)$ is: $\nabla f(x) =  2A x$. Now, plugging in this gradient in the Lipschitz definition,

\begin{align}
\left\lVert \nabla f (x) - \nabla f (y) \right\rVert \leq L \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert , \forall x , y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, 
\end{align}

such that
\begin{align}
\left\lVert Ax - Ay \right\rVert = \left\lVert A\left(x - y\right) \right\rVert \leq L \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert.
\end{align}

Now, if I apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to the left hand side,  then
\begin{align}
\left\lVert 2A\left(x - y\right) \right\rVert \leq 2\left\| A \right\| \left\lVert x - y \right\rVert,
\end{align}
implies that best $L$ is twice a matrix norm of $A$ induced by a vector norm.

> Am I correct?

Comment: Looks good except for a missing $2$. It is sufficient to note that the derivative $ (2Ax)^T$ is linear hence Lipschitz.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you so much.

Comment: It is worth noting that this bound is in general the sharpest constant you can get.